# How to Calculate change between rows in Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a daily sales record column. And from it I want to create two new columns. That keep track of the change from a month a go. For each day on the record. How would I go about doing this in Pandas Data frame. new to pandas and stuck here. 
here is a sample data set

[image: sample dataset]

And what I am looking for is to create a new column "Change from a month ago", 
which will tracks the difference between in daily sales between today and 30 days ago.

Comment: Please provide some data, at least some example of what your current dataframe is, and if possible, what do you expect to achieve and what have you tried so far. That way we can understand the issue and help you achieve a solution, otherwise the question is too broad itself

Comment: can you define `a month ago`, is it 30 days ago?

Comment: @ Shijith Yes a month is 30 days ago.

Comment: So 1 month before March 1 2020 would be January 31, and 1 month before April 1 would be March 2? Looks like a rather uncommon convention...

Comment: @Celius Stingher I have added added a sample data to the question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [pandas.DataFrame.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

```
df['new_col'] = df.sales.diff(periods=30)
```

this will find the difference of current row and 30 rows above (this may or may not be 30 days ago)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to invent your own convention for what is *one month before* but the common one is already implemented if `pd.DateOffset()`.

If you use it, you can build a delta column that way:

```
df['delta'] = df['Daily Sales'] - df.merge(df[['Date', 'Daily Sales']]
                                           .assign(M1 = df['Date']
                                             + pd.DateOffset(months=1))
             .drop_duplicates('M1').drop(columns='Date')
             .rename({'Daily Sales': 'prev'}, axis=1),
         left_on='Date', right_on='M1', how='left')['prev']
```

The decomposition of the above (magic) formule is:

- extract only the `Date` and `Dayly Sailes` columns for further processing
- add one month to the `Date` column and name it `M1`
- drop duplicates on that date that could occur because of the use of `DateOffset`
- rename the `Daily Sales` command to `prev`
- merge it by common dates (using `M1` column) with the original dataframe
- the one month difference is the difference between the `Daily Sailes` column of the original dataframe and the prev column in the merged one.

Answer (score -1):

Getting a sense of the data you're using would certainly make it a lot easier to answer this. However, a common way to do it is by creating a new column in pandas using the `Series.shift` operation in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [10, 20, 15, 30, 45],
                   'Col2': [13, 23, 18, 33, 48],
                   'Col3': [17, 27, 22, 37, 52]})

df['Col4'] = df.Col1.shift(periods=-3) # reference df.Col1 value from 3 rows back
```

You can use this new column to do any arithmetic/algorithmic computation hereon.

Comment: Thank you @Naman  I will try your method. I have edited the question since then. If it helps clarify.